# How to remove “mod_cloudflare” from CentOS Apache

Tags: linux, centos, cloudflare

I did install `mod_cloudflare` but I need to uninstall it

I have zero knowledge about command line.

I installed it by running :

```
yum install libtool git apr apr-devel apr-util apr-util-devel -y
cd /usr/local/src
git clone https://github.com/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare.git
 cd mod_cloudflare
/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs -a -i -c mod_cloudflare.c
service httpd restart && /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -M|grep cloudflare
```

Comment: An Apache module is removed from the file `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf` : Find the command which perhaps may look like `LoadModule cloudflare_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_cloudflare.so`, comment the line or delete it, also delete the `.so` file it points to, then restart Apache. Does this solve the problem?